# Deriving a distribution from the recursion of moments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a recursion for the moments of a distribution I am interested in. The recursion I have is
$$\mathbb E[X^n]=\frac{\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}{n+1\choose j}\mathbb E[Y^j] \mathbb E[X^{n+1-j}]}{(n+1)k}$$
where $Y$ is some given random variable, $k$ is a constant. Is it possible to get a distribution hose moments match with these moments. If not, is it possible to get a distribution whose say first $m$ moments match? Any reference will be appreciated

Comment: [Hamburger moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem)